# Dealing with internal dependencies when publishing to central repository (maven central) and generating release pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, devops, pom.xml, sonatype

So I'm currently working in publishing a java library to the maven central repository using sonatype, The thing is that my core library (the one I'm trying to push) has some internal dependencies which I'm not sure how to add to the deployment process.
i.e
` 
com.internal.dep
messages-dep

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.internal.dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>messages-api-dep</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.internal.dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>messages-control-dep</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
   etc...`
```

My current thought is to upload them as separate libraries to the repository and then make dependencies for that. However I'm not sure how good is that approach.

Also I need to generate a release pom including the dependencies cause the one we currently use for internal deployment includes unnecessary and probably sensitive information.

Comment: If there are internal dependencies which are not published into public means those dependencies can not being used without the internal ones. You could define them as scope:provided

Comment: Don't publish it publicly if it depends on private stuff. What's the purpose?

Comment: @GaëlJ to have our libraries available from maven central for clients to consume

Comment: But if your library has a hard dependency on your private stuff. How will the clients consume the private stuff?